# The type "class *" has not been enhanced JPA exception

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I am running WebSphere v8, and using JPA persistence in a Java EE 6 environment.

When I attempt to run code that deals with a particular entity, I run into this exception:

> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type "class au.com.combined.domain.changeroutine.ChangeRoutineConsumedPK" has not been enhanced.

However, [this article](http://webspherepersistence.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/openjpa-enhancement.html) says that my classes should already be enhanced at runtime. ChangeRoutineConsumedPK is an Embeddable Class. Could someone take a look at my class and tell me what i'm doing wrong? thank you.

**ChangeRoutineConsumed:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = ChangeRoutineConsumed.TABLE_NAME)
public class ChangeRoutineConsumed extends BaseBusinessObject {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "COCHANGEROUTINECONSUMED";

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChangeRoutineConsumedPK id;

    protected ChangeRoutineConsumed() {
        super();
    }

    public ChangeRoutineConsumed(@Min(1) long changeRoutineId, @NotNull String consumedBy){
        this(new ChangeRoutineConsumedPK(changeRoutineId, consumedBy));
    }

    public ChangeRoutineConsumed(@NotNull ChangeRoutineConsumedPK id){
        super();
        setId(id);
    }
    ...
    public int hashCode(){...};
    public boolean equals(Object obj){...}
}
```

**ChangeRoutineConsumedPK:**

```
@Embeddable
public class ChangeRoutineConsumedPK {

    @Column
    private long changeRoutineId;
    @Column
    private String consumedBy;

    public ChangeRoutineConsumedPK(){}

    public ChangeRoutineConsumedPK(long changeRoutineId, String consumedBy) {
        setChangeRoutineId(changeRoutineId);
        setConsumedBy(consumedBy);
    }
    ...

    public int hashCode() {...}
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}
}
```

Comment: also it happens when there is no @Embeddable in JPA key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ChangeRoutineConsumedPK class was not added to the persistence.xml and i had turned off automatic class scanning.

Adding the class to the persistence.xml fixed the problem

```
<persistence-unit ...>
...
<class>au.com.combined.domain.changeroutine.ChangeRoutineConsumedPK</class>
...
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are executing from main class pass below parameter in execution
java -javaagent:/openjpa.jar com.xyz.Main

if using eclipse give above value in run Configuration > arguments > VM arguments.

Comment: Just one correction.  In WebSphere you don't need to use a javaagent for enhancement.  The JPA runtime will enhance your entities automatically (except in some cases where a user is using application managed entity managers).  Finally, in the case where a javaagent is needed (e.g. Eclipse/JSE environment), you need not specify your main class, simply do a -javaagent:<path to jar>; where "<path to jar>" is the location of your OpenJPA jar.  Any classes listed in the persistence.xml file will be enhanced, nothing else (as the originator of this post found out and mentioned in their answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to an answer above, on MacOS in Intellij I added the following to the JUnit run arguments:

`-javaagent:/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.openjpa/openjpa/bundles/openjpa-3.1.1.jar`

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error in Idea and mvn clean install -DskipTest -U worked.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer.